# Prove that $(A^\dagger)^\ast= (A^\ast)^\dagger $

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators, pseudoinverse

> Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$. Prove that $(A^\dagger)^\ast= (A^\ast)^\dagger $ where $A^\dagger$ is the Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse of $A$.

My attempt:

\begin{align}
(A^\dagger)^\ast &= ((A^\ast A)^{-1}A^\ast)^\ast\newline&= A^{\ast\ast}((A^\ast A)^{-1})^\ast \newline &= A(A^\ast A)^{-1}
\end{align}

Then,

\begin{align}
(A^\ast)^\dagger &= (A^{\ast\ast}A^\ast)^{-1}A^{\ast\ast}\newline&= (AA^\ast)^{-1}A
\end{align}

Now I'm stuck, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what's your definition of Moore-Penrose inverse? You are using that it has linearly independent columns, which is not given as far as I can tell from the quoted statement.

Comment: I may be missing something but $A A^*$ and $A^* A$ both invertible - forces the columns and rows of $A$ both to be linearly-independent - which forces $A$ to be square and invertible - which makes the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse the regular inverse of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{gather*}AA^*A=AA^*A\\
(AA^*)^{-1}AA^*A(A^*A)^{-1}=(AA^*)^{-1}AA^*A(A^*A)^{-1}\\
A(A^*A)^{-1} = (AA^*)^{-1}A\\
(A^{\dagger})^*=(A^*)^{\dagger}
\end{gather*}$$